# Salesforce.com Foundation Relationships Package record type incorrect for 'related to' contact

Tags: npsp

I have the Salesforce.com Foundation Relationships package installed that allows for Contact-to-Contact connections and automatic creation of Relationships between Contacts. The issue I'm having is that when I create a new relationship between 2 contacts of a certain record type, the record type of the relationship created on the related contact is always the default.

How can I change this so that the the automatically created relationship is of the same record type?

1)
**Created Sibling record type Relationship**

[image: relationship created]

2)
**Automatically created default Spouse, record type Relationship**

[image: automatically created relationship]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current version of the Salesforce.com Foundation's Relationships package that is part of the Nonprofit Starter Pack does not use Record Types. It uses a field called Type to define both the relationship and reciprocal relationship.  These relationship definitions of what makes one relationship a reciprocal to another (Mother to Son, Uncle to Nephew) are defined in the custom settings of the Relationships package.

Information about how to configure the Relationships settings can be found here:
http://salesforcefoundation.screenstepslive.com/s/npsp/m/Relationships

I'm not sure how you got Record Types however, this must have been something custom that your administrator/developer added on top of the Relationships package that is creating this confusion.  I recommend removing all Record Types entirely from the Relationships object that is part of the package and instead relying on the Type field that is included.

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what I needed to know. We had a consultant here for a while that really screwed things up for us.